# numberOfRowsInSection Error

Tags: swift, uitableview, variables, segue

I'm getting a nil and I don't know why. Every time I select `tableViewController1` and perform a segue it crashes and sends me the error to `tableViewController2`. I set the identifier and set the class to each tableViewController in the storyboard. What i'm trying to do is pass data from `tableViewController1` to `tableViewController2`

This is from `tableViewController1`

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let magazines = MagazineTableViewController()
        magazines.customInit(magazinesindex: indexPath.row, title: topics[indexPath.row])
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "company", sender: nil)
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
```

And this is `tableViewController2`

```
let MagazinesData = [//an array containing arrays of magazines]
var magazinesIndex: Int!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

func customInit(magazinesindex: Int, title: String) {
    self.magazinesIndex = magazinesindex // this is where the error is
    self.title = title
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return MagazinesData[magazinesIndex].count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MagazineTableViewCell
    cell.magazineTitle?.text = MagazinesData[magazinesIndex][indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, your approach is completely wrong.

Instead of creating a new instance of `MagazineTableViewController` which is **not** equal to the destination controller of the segue you have to implement `prepare(for segue` and pass the data to the `destination` property of the segue.

- Change `didSelectRowAt` to

  ```
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "company", sender: indexPath)
      tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
  }
  ```
- Implement `prepare(for segue` like this

  ```
  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
      if segue.identifier.rawValue == "company" { 
        let destinationController = segue.destination as! MagazineTableViewController
        let indexPath = sender as! IndexPath
        destinationController.customInit(magazinesindex: indexPath.row, title: topics[indexPath.row])

      }
  }
  ```

Comment: thanks! I completely forgot about the prepare for segue